# Why is the following bash command not working properly?

Tags: bash, redirect

I have the following bash command:

```
$(ls -l /var/ | grep www) > cat folder_exists
```

but it is not working properly. What I hope to achieve is a command, that checks to see if there is a www folder located inside the `/var/` folder, and prints the result of that particular command to the file `folder_exists`. I have also tried to retype the command numerous times, example given

```
cat $(ls -l /var/ | grep www) > folder_exists
```

or even

```
cat $(ls -l /var | grep www) > folder_exists
```

just in case that slash did the damage, but to no avail.

My problem is that even though I am creating the file `folder_exists`, I fail to print the output to it. Could somebody please show me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better do that:

```
if [ -d /var/www ] ; then touch folder_exists ; else touch folder_absent ; fi
```

The first version of the command does the following: `$( ... )` is first replaced by whatever was produced by `...`. Since you call ls -l | grep www, you are either getting a line with multiple words, or nothing. In the first case it is attempted to be executed, but that makes little sense. What will you get if you type

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 Aug 20 13:48 log
```

at the command prompt? There is no command called `drwxr-xr-x`. If you use the `cat $( ls -l /var | grep www)` form, then first the `$( ... )` is replaced by what was produced by `...`, then cat interpretes it as a list of files to cat (starting with `drwxr-xr-x`; most likely, there is no such file).

Moreover, if you attempt to do something like that:

```
command > cat file
```

What will happen is that `cat` is interpreted as a filename to store the output of `command`, and not as a command. To interpret `cat` as a command, you need a pipe sign, like you correctly used in ls | grep:

```
command | cat
```

However, if your purpose is to store the output of command in a file, then just use

```
command > file
```

As a matter of fact, you could do

```
ls /var | grep www > file
```

This file will be empty only if there is no www folder in ls. But beware! if there is a folder  /var/ewwwocks, then the file will also contain a line. Better to use simply

```
ls /var/www > file
```

Long story short, use the conditional construct if ... ; then ... ; else ... ; fi

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Clarified many things in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis.

```
 ls -l /var/ | grep www > folder_exists
```

Works just fine.

Comment: Not really, if you want to check for "www" folder and not for any other folder that contains the string "www".

Answer (score 1):

The `-l` argument to `ls` causes it to include a lot of extraneous information that will muck up grep. The correct command would be `ls -a /var/ | grep www > folder_exists`.

Comment: I do not think that there is an issue with the information provided by the -l flag, grep has gone through a mountain of information for me in the past without any issues. The only issue I could possibly have might be latency, but I do not suffer from such issues.

Comment: Though if one of the folders is owned by a user with `www` in their name then it will fail with the `-l` option.

Comment: I'll tell you what: I will thumbs you up if you could explain to me why it would fail, because I do not understand it.

Comment: I make a group called `wwwgroup` and create a folder in `/var` called `something` which is owned by group `wwwgroup`. If I run `ls -l | grep www` I get `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Aug 15 21:35 www/` \n `drwxr-xr-x  2 root wwwgroup     4096 Aug 15 21:35 something/`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `find` for such a task:

```
find /var -type d -name '*www*' -maxdepth 1
```

- `-name '*www*'` matches anything named something with `www`, use `-iname` if the match should be case insensitive.
- `find` is recursive by default, so the `maxdepth` option ensures that only `/var/*www*` are matched.
- `-type d` specifies that it should be a directory.

Comment: Nice answer! I will definitely try your approach, as it may be useful in other case too. Thank you.